# Multiple entries in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm using a PostgreSQL 9.3 Database to create a small Userdatabase. One user can be a part of different groups.

There are 2 Tables in the Database:
 *user*  and *group*
The data type of all columns is text

Every row in *user* is a single user, every row in *group* is a single group.
One column in user should be *groups*

How may i configure the *groups*-column to add multiple entries of *group* to a single user

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a standard many-to-many relationship in a relational database.

You solve this problem by creating a mapping table between users and groups:

If you have something like this currently:

```
create table users (id integer primary key, user_name text);
create table groups (id integer primary key, group_name text);
```

The mapping table would look something like this:

```
create table user_groups
(
   user_id not null references users,
   group_id not null references groups,
   primary key (user_id, group_id)
);
```

By using `(user_id, group_id)` as the primary key, you make sure that a user can only be mapped to the same group once.